# How to implement event listener for any objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to implement custom event with this functionality:

- create custom event
- after callback of ajax dispatch event
- any object in document (div, grid, ...) can register listener of this custom event
- when event is fired, all objects which have registered listener event call any methods

I tried created custom event (no problem):

```
var eventFilterRefresh = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
eventFilterRefresh.initEvent("onFilterCancel", true, true);
```

Register event:

```
var dv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
dv.addEventListener('onFilterCancel', function (e) {
    alert();
}, false);
```

Dispatch event - here is problem. I don't wont call dispatchEvent on conrete object. I want call generaly dispatchEvent and all objects which have registered event makes methods:

```
var myDiv= document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.dispatchEvent(eventFilterCancel);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a [pubsub](https://github.com/datibbaw/pubsub.js) library is what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fire an event from a single context so that listeners bound to a variety of other elements will trigger on it. You will need to fire the event from the context of each of the elements with the relevant listener.

The easiest way to do this is to add a hook like a class name to all of the elements that have the event listener and then use that hook to dispatch the event for each element.

```js
//Add a hook when you register the listener
var dv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
dv.addEventListener('onFilterCancel', function (e) {
    alert();
}, false);
dv.className += " js-filter-cancel";

//Use the hook to fire the event for all listeners
var myDivs= document.querySelectorAll('.js-filter-cancel');

for(var i in myDivs) {
  if(!myDivs.hasOwnProperty(i))
    continue;
  
  myDivs[i].dispatchEvent(eventFilterCancel);
}
```